# Cannot find Network Message ID in Message Trace

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, microsoft-365

I'm viewing a message trace from https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/#/messagetrace

If I expand "More Information" on the selected email, I see "Message id".   When I go to https://security.microsoft.com/reportsubmission and try to submit it, it asks for a "Network Message ID".  I tried entering the "Message id" from above, but it says it's invalid.  I can't find "Network Message ID" (or any other ID) anywhere in the trace.  What am I missing?

How do I submit a message to Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Network Message ID: This is a GUID value that's available in the X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id header in the message, or in the X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id header in quarantined messages. For more details: [Submit a questionable email to Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/admin-submission?view=o365-worldwide#submit-a-questionable-email-to-microsoft)

Here are some steps for your reference:

1.open the email and click message option, you will see internet headers:
[image]

2.Then you run EXRCA to run Message Header Analyzer and find the X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
[image]

Comment: hmm, I'm quite sure I used to be able to submit messages for analysis from an admin portal.  Having to access the client is very inconvenient for me and the user.

Comment: I have done some test, i cannot find the network message id in message trace results, but i have found the -MessageTraceId is the Exchange Network Message ID. For more details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-messagetracedetail?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score -1):

Yes same issue on this side, if I expand "More Information" on the selected email, I see "Message id". When I go to reportsubmission and try to submit it, it asks for a "Network Message ID". I tried entering the "Message id" from above, but it says it's invalid. I can't find "Network Message ID" (or any other ID) anywhere in the trace.
I want to know how to find the correct network message ID for submission without asking the client for eml or msg files.

Comment: Ok found the solution finally.
You need to go to: https://protection.office.com/threatexplorer
Search for scam emails directly from here and submit them from there itself without any message network ID.

Comment: That page seems to only list phishing/malware that was detected. I cannot find the message in question there.

Comment: Glad you have found the solution, you could mark your reply as best answer if some people encounter the same issue they could find the solution quickly:)